# choosing the function of a random variable with the lowest variance w.r.t.o the mean of that random variable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Consider a real gaussian random variable with mean $\theta$ and unit variance. Let $y$ be an observation of the random variable. The objective is to estimate $\theta$ over all possible $y$. Let $\hat{y}$ be a one to one function of $y$. By that, I mean, given $\hat{y}$, one can find the corresponding $y$ uniquely. Then consider the term
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{\hat{y}}=\mathbb{E}_y((\hat{y}-\theta)^2)=\theta^2-2\theta\mathbb{E}_y(\hat{y})+\mathbb{E}_y(\hat{y}^2)
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{E}_y(.)$ denotes the expectation. Now consider the choice $\hat{y}=y$, it is not that hard to see that $\epsilon_{\hat{y}}=1$ at that choice. Is there a way to prove that no other choice of $\hat{y}$ gives a lower value value of $\epsilon_{\hat{y}}$?. This implies that the observation is the best estimate of the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particular case of the [Cramer Rao bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound).

Here under the hypothesis that $E\hat y = y$, $$l(x,\theta) = \log f(x,\theta)
= -\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} - \frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2}\\
I(\theta) = E[\partial_l(x,\theta)^2] = E[(x-\theta)^2] = 1\\
Var \ \hat y\ge \frac 1{I(\theta)} = 1 = Var \ y
$$

Comment: is your argument that variance of any unbiased estimator is greater than or equal to the inverse of fischer information and thus $\hat{y}=y$ is the only choice that achieves that?

Comment: my argument implies that it attained by this estimator, not that this is the only one.

Comment: How do we prove the uniqueness? or is there any other estimator which has the same expected error?